# Firebase offline support

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner to mobile app's development and I was trying to develop a chat app with the help of online lectures and youtube videos. I was successful in developing it and connecting that to firebase.
What I had noticed is that while when my phone is not connected to internet my app is not showing details of groups and other stuffs. Even after enabling data connection it is showing the details after some time delay. While connecting to fire base database  for the first time I had selected server location to default (US). I am located  in India. Whether this distance is causing the problem in delay in getting the items?. Whether any one can tell me how my app can show the details in while phone is not connected to internet like Whatsapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please enable Disk Persistence in your app. That will help.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

For keeping data fresh

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

For details check disk Persistence in Firebase documents.

Comment: Thanks you very much , its working .. you  save my day ,,,.Thanks